# Помогите с подключением VST плагинов в программу на Python

Tags: python, аудио, dll

Хочу написать меленькую DAW на python (Ради интереса). Но понял, что не понимаю как подключать к программе vst плагины и взаимодействовать с ними. Кто сталкивался с этим, или хотя бы примерно понимает как это реализовать отпишитесь пожалуйста. Сами плагины представляют собой dll файлы.